# UICollectionView Change Cell Height with Pan Gesture Recognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a pan gesture recognizer on a collection view, and I want the height of the cell to increase as the user drags up on the cell (in a 1:1 ratio, also there is only one cell on the screen at a time).

I have the pan gesture recognizer setup (currently on the collectionView, but should it be on the cell itself?), and I am adjusting an autolayout constraint on the collectionView, however I don't know how to increase the height of the collectionViewCell itself:

```
@IBAction func panGestureMove(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch sender.state {
    case .began:
        startPoint = sender.translation(in: self.view)
        break
        case .changed:
        if(self.startPoint.y > sender.translation(in: self.view).y){
            // Swiping Up
            collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = 120 + (self.startPoint.y - sender.translation(in: self.view).y)
        }
        break
        case .ended:
        self.collectionViewBottomConstraint.constant = 0.0
        break
    default:
        print("Shouldn't be here")
    }
}
```

How do I change the height of the cell?